# "grpc_message":"Received RST_STREAM with error code 8","grpc_status":1

Tags: ios, grpc

I'm receiving an error from a GRPCProtoCall when trying to upload a larger photo. I was originally using the editor that came from UIImagePickerController that would crop photos to a smaller square. But with a 3rd party cropper, I'm now able to grab full photos that are too large and cause an error.

I've seen online that there may be a 4MB limit to a CPBMessage, but my image is nowhere near that size.

After looking into the gRPC status codes, it looks like some iOS resource may be exhausted. It doesn't look like a memory issue.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this?

> Error Domain=io.grpc Code=1
>   "{"created":"@1559153090.024359000","description":"Error received from
>   peer
>   ...","file":".../Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1041,"grpc_message":"Received
>   RST_STREAM with error code 8","grpc_status":1}"
>   UserInfo={io.grpc.HeadersKey={

Comment: As the error message suggests, it is likely that the server side sends a RST_STREAM frame, and the reason (8) is CANCEL. Check your server logs or app to see why the call gets canceled.

Comment: ```io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: io.grpc.netty.NettyServerStream$TransportState: Frame size 13212915 exceeds maximum: 4194304.``` this is i got in server log. Now how to increase frame size in datastore emulator?